# Using TMRpcm library, the audio does not play

Tags: arduino-uno, sd-card, audio, tmrpcm

I'm using the https://github.com/TMRh20/TMRpcm/wiki library to play wav files from an SD card to a speaker I have attached to my Arduino.

I have run separate tests/programs that ensures:

1. my speaker is connected properly and can play sound
2. my SD file is connected properly as it can read and files, text files.

However, I'm trying to use the `tmrpcm.play("example.wav")` command and nothing is happening. I used wav files that for sure works (from a demo I found online) so it's not the wav file problem.

Anyone have any clue on what is going on and how I can fix this?

Answer (score 3):

This is now 5 months later - but I recently had the same problem.

Because the TMRpcm library plays through pulse width modulation, make sure your speakers are hooked up to a PWM capable pin.

That caused me no end of headaches trying to figure out.